# How do I know if this quadrilateral is cyclic?

Tags: quadrilateral

[image]

There are some pairs of angles that are equal to each other, but none of the values are known.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The qudrilaterial is cyclic because the two congruent angles $\angle DCA$ and $\angle DBA$ are inscribed angles from the chord $DA$.

Thus you can use [Brahmagupta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral#Area) for the area.

Answer (score 1):

A convex quadrilateral polygon in a plane is cyclic if, and only if, its opposite angles are supplementary.